# core data many-to-many count

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a model containing 2 entities in a many-to-many inverse relationship - Lets say
Movie and Actor.

**Movie**

> - name
> - hit (1 or 0 indicating if it is a blockbuster or not)
> - actors (to-many inverse relationship)

**Actor**

> - name
> - movies (to-many inverse relationship)

Now I would like to show list of all actors

1. showing a count of hit movies they have acted as a percentage of total movies they have acted
2. sorted by this percentage desc.

I would like to know how to query this count using `countForFetchRequest` instead of traversing via `executeFetchRequest`? Is this possible?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?